# How to add link rel tags on paginated posts?

Tags: functions, seo

I'm using the following code in functions.php to add rel prev/next tags to paginated contents:

```
function add_rel_nextprev_to_paginated_content()
{
global $paged;
if ( get_previous_posts_link() ) { ?><link rel="prev" href="<?php echo get_pagenum_link( $paged - 1 ); ?>"><?php }
if ( get_next_posts_link() ) { ?><link rel="next" href="<?php echo get_pagenum_link( $paged + 1 ); ?>"><?php }
}
remove_action('wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head');
add_action('wp_head', 'add_rel_nextprev_to_paginated_content');
```

This works well for categories, tags and other content, but not the posts that were split into multiple pages by WP's  tag.

However, I can't find the right function to call the next page of a paginated post.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found a code snippet that exactly does the job as desired.

See https://orbitingweb.com/blog/adding-next-and-prev-tags-to-paginated-posts/ for details and further explanations.